# How do I convert list of tuple of dictionary of list to a csv file?

Tags: python, tuples, nested-lists

I have a nested list that looks something like this:

list:

```
[('CN=GON,OU=App,OU=Groups,DC=com', {'member': [b'CN=user1,OU=Users,DC=com', b'CN=user2,OU=Users,DC=com',]})]
```

What should I do to convert this to a csv file that looks something like this:

out.file:

```
user1
user2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

with the list you provided :

```py
lst = [('CN=GON,OU=App,OU=Groups,DC=com', {'member': [b'CN=user1,OU=Users,DC=com', b'CN=user2,OU=Users,DC=com']})]

csvOutput = []

for user in lst[0][1]['member']:
    strUser = user.decode("utf-8").split(',')
    newRow = []
```

Now, if you want only the the `'CN'` as an output :

```py
    newRow.append(strUser[0].split("=")[1])

    csvOutput.append(newRow)
```

Or if you want all the data :

```py
    for data in strUser:
        newRow.append(data.split("=")[1])

    csvOutput.append(newRow)
```

And finally, to write this in a csv file :

```py
import csv

with open('yourFile.csv', 'w') as f:
    write = csv.writer(f)
    write.writerows(csvOutput)
```

Note that the last part can be done with pandas as well.